# at command won't run python scripts

Tags: python, python-3.x, at-job

I have a Python script I would like to run at a specified time however when using the at command the script refuses to execute I have tried using a shell script(an.sh) to call the Python script but it still doesn't work it seemingly runs the job without executing the script

an.sh

```bash
python3 AandT/A_notifier.py ABC
```

A_notifier.py

```py
import tkinter
Root = tkinter.Tk()
i = tkinter.Label(text="Hello World")
i.pack()
Root.mainloop()
```

I tried running the file directly using at. it did nothing
i tried running it through a shell script. it did nothing again
i tried switching the Python script out for a simple hello world one. and it did nothing
i also tried removing aplay from the script(an.sh)and that didn't work ether

Comment: "Didn't work" is useless as a problem description. We need to know _how it failed_; if you aren't collecting enough information to _know_ how it failed, do that! For example, you can run `exec 2>/tmp/err.log; python3 AandT/A_notifier.py ABC` and then read that `err.log` file.

Comment: _Most often_, this is because you're relying on setup (like environment variables -- PATH, PYTHONPATH, etc) or permissions (like access to sound devices) that your interactive session has access to but the at daemon doesn't. But we'd need an exact error message to do more than guess.

Comment: err.log

[?2004h(venv) ]0;effectimminent@linus: ~/PycharmProjects/project231l[01;32meffectimminent@linus[00m:[01;34m~/PycharmProjects/project231[00m$

Comment: i wiill clarify it seemingly runs the job with executing the script. ps. sorry for the bad problem description the original post was written at like 2am

and i dont think it is setup as the python script is basically just hello world

Comment: Be sure you [edit] enough information into the question to make the problem solvable; comments don't count as part of the question (they're transient by nature, prone to editing/deletion/etc and not versioned). And if your program is truly a "hello world", how do you know if it ran or not?

Comment: ...if, f/e, you're using the program to create a file, then we want to look at how you're referring to that file; using a relative PATH instead of an absolute one and then not doing an appropriate `cd` in your at job is an easy way to get the problem at hand.

Comment: First you say "Python scripts" -- you didn't tell us tkinter was involved. Trying to connect to the GUI from a daemon adds a _huge_ amount of complexity (for the most part, GUI access is deliberately only for things _the user starts from a GUI_); it's not expected to work out-of-the-box.

Comment: _At minimum_ you need a DISPLAY environment variable, but you probably also need an Xauthority token, and there's the question of whether your distro also has SELinux hardening or other reinforcement to keep daemons out of the GUI. (This is important because being able to connect to the X server can be used to run keyloggers or other such maliciousness).

Comment: Anyhow -- in general, at this point, I would back up and ask what you _actually intend to accomplish_. For a lot of purposes, I'd argue that `at` is the wrong tool for the job in the first place, and you should be using a user-local systemd service configured to have access to your GUI session; systemd services can be automatically started by timer units, so you can get your `at`-like functionality.

Comment: it does not actually need to run anything involving tkinter that was just the first way i thought of to make a non console output in retrospect that was horrible idea and running it using a script not using tkinter made it work fine my i should not have been doing this at 2am i probably wouldn't have had to ask this question sorry for wasting peoples time i should have looked at this with a non-sleepy set of eyes

Comment: Perhaps it might make sense to delete the question, then?